# Can a Simple Random Walk be describe as the difference of 2 Bernoulli Variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let

\begin{equation}X =
    \left|
        \begin{array}{cc}
                1 &  p \\
                -1 &  1-p \\
        \end{array} 
    \right.
\end{equation}
Is it valid to say $$X = Y - Z$$ where $$Y _\tilde \ B(p) \ and \ Z _\tilde \  B(1-p) $$ Would Y and Z be i.i.d

Comment: $Y$ and $Z$ cannot be independent.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ and $Z$ have the same distribution then $EX=EY-EZ=0$ so $p =\frac  1 2$.

If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent then $Y-Z$ takes at least three values with positive probability so it cannot have the same distribution as $X$.